# What is the Fill Down hotkey in Excel on a French system?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hotkeys

I am using Excel in French, and would like to use the Fill Down function which copies the first value's formula and puts the updated formula into each cell which is selected beneath.

At the moment I must use the mouse to drag the little square in the bottom right hand corner of the cursor in the cell from which I want to copy.

On an English system, I could do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. What is the French equivalent?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Presumably Ctrl+D does something else on a French keyboard? Also - check what Excel says: In the menu goto Edit->Fill, what does "Fill Down" have next to it? Obviously I've Ctrl+D here (on an English system), but if your Excel is also French this could give you the answer.

Comment: If you want to put that in as an answer I can accept it! I had become so used to using CTRL-D that I had forgotten that it ever existed in a menu! In the end it's CTRL-B for Edition->Recopier->En Bas. CTRL-D is to the right: Edition->Recopier->A droite

Comment: comment upgraded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Ctrl + B in the French Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You should check what Excel says - In the menu goto `Edit`->`Fill`, and it should tell you the keyboard shortcut next to the `Fill Down` option.

On my English version it tells me `Ctrl+D`, as you'd expect, but if your Excel is also French this should give you the answer.